# Actions on Google returns in simulator "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again."

Tags: dialogflow-es

Debug tab:

```
{
  "response": "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "",
  "audioResponse": ""
}
```

I create the sample project in Dialogflow and it works, but in the simulator Actions on Google it doesn't!

Comment: I got the same issue. Even very simple project that responds static texts failed to run on  Actions on Google simulator. 
Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 9):

Please read the "Preview the app" section of this page:

https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app?hl=en

To preview your app:

Turn on the following permissions on the Activity controls page for your Google account:

- Web & App Activity
- Device Information
- Voice & Audio Activity

You need to do this to use the Actions Simulator, which lets you test your actions on the web without a hardware device.

Activity control page: https://myactivity.google.com/activitycontrols

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the Actions console and enter the 'Backend services' - it's in the left menu below the 'Simulator'. 
There should be one card for Cloud Functions. Does this say, that there's an error? If so, you can find out more in the logs of Firebase Functions, which is linked in this card.

Answer (score -1):

Check the settings and permissions, if you are a developer, owner etc. of the application. I got this fixed by changing the settings...need to dig a little more to understand the exact reason. Will do an update if I understand more